# AngularJS - My error messages aren't updating when their trigger variables are changed in the scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, watch

I'm pretty new to Angular so this is probably a really simple question with a really obvious answer, but I haven't been able to work it out from reading through similar posts so I figured I'd ask here.

Basically I have a text input field, and I'm trying to make an error message appear/dissapear beneath it in real time depending on whether it does or doesn't have any content in it (I also have other fields with different error messages that will appear/dissapear based on different criteria though, so just setting it as a required field as a quick fix won't work for my other other purposes)

As far as I can tell, the trigger variable is updating exactly as it should when I enter or delete text, but the error message itself apparently isn't getting the memo and is just staying as it is.

Here's a cut down version of what I have so far

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" name="createRiskAssessmentForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRiskNameId" class="col-sm-2">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input id="inputRiskNameId" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="riskAssessmentTable.name" name="riskNameField">
                <div ng-hide="$scope.nameFieldHasContent" class="alert alert-danger">This field is required!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function (module) {
    module.controller('CreateRiskAssessmentTableController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.$watch('riskAssessmentTable.name', function(name) {
            if (name == '') {
                $scope.nameFieldHasContent = false;
            }
            else {
                $scope.nameFieldHasContent = true;
            }
            console.log('Name field has content?: ' + $scope.nameFieldHasContent);
        });

    }]);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Angular, but I remember having a similar issue. Do you see the same if you change the model to `someTempVariableForTesting` instead of `riskAssessmentTable.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think this line is correct:

`<div ng-hide="$scope.nameFieldHasContent" class="alert alert-danger">This field is required!</div>`

remove the '$scope.' part on ng-hide, changing it to:

`<div ng-hide="nameFieldHasContent" class="alert alert-danger">This field is required!</div>`

You could also checkout the angular directives ng-dirty and ng-valid to help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the ng-modal is pointing to object `riskAssessmentTable.name`, you have to pre-define the `riskAssessmentTable` in controller. Try the below code.

```
module.exports = function (module) {
    module.controller('CreateRiskAssessmentTableController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.riskAssessmentTable = {};

        $scope.$watch('riskAssessmentTable.name', function(name) {
            if (name == '') {
                $scope.nameFieldHasContent = false;
            }
            else {
                $scope.nameFieldHasContent = true;
            }
            console.log('Name field has content?: ' + $scope.nameFieldHasContent);
        });

    }]);
};
```